# IndexError list index out of range

Tags: python, csv, indexing

I have a CSV files with data. It look like this:

```
0000000000000000,125000000.0,609997.561693,6760380.58538,nan,7
0000000000010001,125000000.0,609997.55824,6760380.69672,nan,7
0000000100000000,125000000.0,609997.551333,6760380.91942,nan,7
0000000100010001,125000000.0,609997.436165,6760381.13875,nan,7
0010010000000000,125000000.0,607992.989435,6760461.19335,nan,7
0010010000010001,125000000.0,607990.388088,6760457.65914,nan,7
```

Now I want to copy 3 columns ( [0], [2], [3] ) into an empty CSV file. This is my program so far:

```
import csv
with open("radar.csv","rb") as csvfile:
    rdr= csv.reader(csvfile)
    with open("table.csv","wb") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer(result)
        for r in rdr:
           wtr.writerow((r[0], r[2], r[3]))
```

Everytime when I run the program there is an "IndexError: list index out of range". There are no empty lines in the file, when I use

```
if len(r) <= 1:
            pass
```

All the lines get passed. If I try the program on an earlier version of the CSV file, which is exactly the same except that the data is unsorted, it works fine. But if I copy only one line of the actual CSV file into the old one, there is the same error in the old one, even if it worked fine before copying.

Comment: Your code works as posted for the inputfile as posted. On a side note, you can save one level of indentation with `with open("radar.csv","rb") as csvfile, open("table.csv","wb") as result:`.

Comment: Yes I know. Could there be something wrong with the format of the lines in the csv file? It should work, but it doesn't... I mean it works fine in the other csv file, which is almost not different.

Comment: Yes, your other inputfile is likely malformatted.

Comment: In addition, you are probably confusing `pass` with an assertion.

Comment: What could be wrong there? I cannot see any difference between the format of the two files.